# Not able to set background image with Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

So I just started out with the Ionic Framework. And I am trying to add a background image. But when I run the application in the browser, I don't see the image. In my console I get a 404 error. I believe my path is correct. I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/04/adding-background-images-to-ionic-framework-apps/) after I was not sure if my css was correct. Which is basically the same as I have got. So does anybody know what the problem is exactly?

[image]

Part of my html code is the following:

```
 <div class="logo"></div>
```

And my css is the following:

```
.logo{
    background-image: url('../img/logo.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 246px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: have you checked the path for images.?

Comment: It's working fine http://jsfiddle.net/7tjsrm9t/

Comment: try adding <img src="../img/logo.jpg"> to check if the image 100% works, sometimes a page doesn't have permission to read

Comment: @pathurs, if I add the image via html then it shows. how to change the permissions ?

Comment: @CodeRomeos, thanks for making the fiddle. i see the code works now in the fiddle. its just strange that it will not show like ../img/logo.png ....

Comment: That was checking the permissions, now we're 100% sure it will work! try reducing your css to just the background-image part, we're gonna start troubleshooting it

Comment: @pathurs: ok so i reduced the code to just showing the image path with width and height.  but still no luck

Comment: We're not allowed to have conversations in the comments I believe, so I'll add an answer instead, hope I can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91005/discussion-between-pathurs-and-gy22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems can occur with just using 'background' in CSS, especially when the container doesn't have any other contents.

Try the following:

1. Adding display: block; with a Width and Height set, this can override any inherited display settings.
2. Reduce the amount of CSS to troubleshoot, sometimes you've just missing a small part, that has moved or hidden the actual container
3. IF all else fails, do it step by step on JSFIDDLE and when it continues to work as required, try copying it over. This also helps you learn